# why the php function load in wrong place

Tags: php, html, css

hello I have a problem with my PHP code I have a function to get a comment for each post on my website the function in working but the data is in a wrong place
as you can see in the picture the comments are in the wrong place and I need to move them to the place in the picture

```
<?php
class posts{
static function getposts(){
    $query = database::query("select * from posts join frinds on frinds.user1_id = posts.user_id or 
 frinds.user2_id= posts.user_id  where frinds.user1_id = ? or frinds.user2_id = 
  ?",array($_COOKIE['uid'],$_COOKIE['uid']));
    if($query->rowCount() > 0){
        $rows=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($rows as $row){
             $id = $row['user_id'];
            // if($id != $_COOKIE['uid']){
                if($id != $_COOKIE['uid']){
                    $post_text = $row['text'];
                    $id= $row['id'];
                    echo posts::postbody($id,$post_text);
               
                  
                }
                
                
        }
        if($id == $_COOKIE['uid']){
            $query = database::query("select * from posts where user_id = ?",array($_COOKIE['uid']));
            if($query->rowCount() > 0){
                $rows=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                foreach($rows as $row){
                    $post_text = $row['text'];
                    echo posts::postbody($row['id'],$post_text);
                }
            }
          }
        }
    }
    static function postbody($id,$post_text){
   
    $body =" <div class='post'>
                    <div class='post_texts' ><p class='post_text'>$post_text</p>
                    
                    
                    </div>
                    <div class='comments'>
                   " .posts::comments($id)."
                   </div>
                    <form method='post'>
                    <input type='text' name='comment'>
                    <input type='submit' name='addcoment'>
                    </form>
                    
                    </div> ";
                    return $body;
   }
   static function creatpost(){
       $query = database::query("INSERT INTO `posts` (`user_id`, `text`) VALUES (?, 
 ?);",array($_COOKIE['uid'],$_POST['text']));
  }
  static function comments($id){
    $query = database::query("select * from comments join posts on comments.post_id = posts.id where 
  posts.id = ?",array($id));
    if($query->rowCount() > 0){
        $rows=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $comment = $row['comment'];
        echo"<p>$comment</p>";
        }
        
    }
   }
 }
?>
```

as you can see 
is where i have the post and <div class'comment'>
where I should have the comments
[image: here is the picture of my error]

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem? And how is this related to CSS?

Comment: I think that it was a design problem

Comment: Please format your code properly with some sane code indentions. It's really hard to follow what happens where when it's all over the place like that.

Comment: I change the format here on this website I will fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your static method call `posts::comments($id)` already uses `echo` to output the comments. While the post body is stored in the variable `$body` which is echoed only later on.

You need to change you code such that the comments are not immediately echoed when they are collected from the database. But that they are either placed in an output buffer or returned to the calling scope. So that they can become part of the actual post body you try to create.

In other words: when calling `posts::comments($id)` you expect to get something back which you try to concatenate to your `$body` variable. But your method never returns something. It only creates output that is send to the client immediately. So it never gets part of that variable where you try to collect the post body.

---

UPDATE:

How can you "collect" the comments to return them all together?

```
static function comments($id){
    $query = database::query("select * from comments join posts on comments.post_id = posts.id where 
  posts.id = ?",array($id));

    if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
        $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $comment = [];
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $comments[] = $row['comment'];
        }
        return implode("\n", $comments);
    }
    return "<p>No comments so far...</p>;
}
```

Comment: so what should I do in this cause

Comment: if I use return it works but with one row @@

Comment: Sure, you need to collect all comments in that method and return _all_ of them.

Comment: so how can I collect them and return them can you explane please ^_^

Comment: I added an answer to that as an UPDATE.

Comment: thank you 
I have an extra question I have a code in Github can I give you the link so you can see the code and rate me?? I want to know if I am doing well or no

and thank you again

Comment: Sorry, but that is not how this site works. I can give you a short impression of the code you published in this question, if you like: you demonstrate a good understanding of basic concepts. You should work on making your code easier to read. Today the most important aspect when it comes to "good" code is whether code is maintainable, especially by others. That requires that it is really easy to follow and understand. So break down your long statements into smaller chunks. And, apparently, you still need to collect a lot of experience in how web technologies work. Take your time, you will!